# How can i switch to next field in web form using Android browser?

Tags: browser

How can i switch to next field in web form using Android browser? There is no tab button, which Im using on my PC.

Answer (score 3):

I use the default Android keyboard and it has a Tab key that pops up beside the space key.  It looks like this: <kbd>–>|</kbd>

Comment: This depends on the page as well, since some pages don't supply information about the order of the fields (tabindex), therefore no "next field button". Occasionally it's annoingly sporadic.

Comment: @onik True. I assume there are other keyboards with a dedicated tab; I wonder how the browser handles it.

Comment: If the "next" button isn't available, you can use the back button to close the keyboard, then tap on the field you want to go to to reopen the keyboard.

Comment: My Samsung Ace inserts tab to input and doesn't go to next field

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the phone as well. If you have a phone with a central trackball, e.g. HTC Desire, the trackball can be used to navigate through links and form fields while browsing.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the phone you use (mine has an arrow-pad), you can use physical navigation to switch between fields. You can also often press "Next" when typing using the virtual keyboard with fields if your phone offers that feature.